# Nginx: URL Redirect and regex

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to clean up url for my blog's (Movable Type) search script using Rewrite in Nginx.

Clean search URL: (xxx= tag name ex. apple)  When I access this URL I get 404 Not Found.

```
http://cgi.blogurl.com/content/brand/apple/
```

Regular Search URL script path:

`http://cgi.blogurl.com/mt/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=1&tag=apple&limit=20`

Here is what I have so far:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name  cgi.blogurl.com;

    if ($host = "cgi.blogurl.com") {
           rewrite ^/([^/]*)/$ /mt/mt-search.cgi?blog_id=1&tag=$1&limit=10 break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `rewrite ^/?content/brand/([^/]+)/?$ /mt/mt...` where `...` represents the segment from your own rule.

Comment: Remove the if statement, given your server name above, it's always true. Secondly since nginx does not do CGI, you have a process setup somewhere that handles it for you, so show that part as well. Last but not least, do a bit of research on regular expressions, just a ten minute read and you will see that this will never match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rewrite ^/?content/brand/([^/]+)/?$ /mt/mt-search.cgi?blog_id=1&tag=$1&limit=10 break;
```